# detecting link checkers (spam filter) in incoming HTTP requests

Tags: xmlhttprequest, user-agent, spam-prevention

We have a site that uses a "one-time" login process for password resets which are not initiated by the user themselves.  (for instance, a password reset that is initiated by an admin or another employee) A URL is sent to the user via email which can then be used to reset their password. The URL can only be visited one time.  (there's more to this for security-sake but I'll keep it simple) Recently, some users have complained that when they visit the link, it has already expired. The end result is that they can't reset their passwords using this feature. We discovered that the users in question have a spam filter or "link checker" in their environment that they do not have access to. This device visits the one-time link before the user is able to, to make sure its safe.

I'm trying to solve this issue and was wondering if there's a way I can detect these type of devices on the web server when the request is made? When the spam filter visits the link, is there something in the http request that would stand apart from a regular browser? Maybe they all use a specific custom HTTP header?  Or maybe there's a regex I could use on the user agent?  I haven't been able to catch one of these yet, so I'm not sure what the request looks like coming from a spam filter.

Anyone know of a way to detect spam filters of any vendor by looking at the http requests? I know it's a long shot but maybe they all use a specific header for reasons such as this?

Comment: Why is the link only valid for one request? That sounds like bad stuff waiting to happen as you have noticed. Fix your flow instead of trying to create a workaround for the broken system.

Comment: For security reasons.  The link allows the user to change their password.

Comment: So what? What do you gain by doing it like that instead of letting it expire after an hour instead?

Comment: It wasn't my design but I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

I got approval to modify the design to remove the one-time aspect of the URL. This solves the issue and saves me the headache. Thanks for the suggestion, @PeeHaa